# Spark streaming gc setup questions

Tags: java, apache-spark, garbage-collection, jvm, spark-streaming

My logic is as follows.

1. Use createDirectStream to get a topic by log type in Kafka.
2. After repartition, the log is processed through various processing.
3. Create a single string using combineByKey for each log type (use StringBuilder).
4. Finally, save to HDFS by log type.

There are a lot of operations that add strings, so GC happens frequently.

How is it better to set up GC in this situation?

//////////////////////

There are various logic, but I think there is a problem in doing combineByKey.

```
rdd.combineByKey[StringBuilder](
    (s: String) => new StringBuilder(s),
    (sb: StringBuilder, s: String) => sb.append(s),
    (sb1: StringBuilder, sb2: StringBuilder) => sb1.append(sb2)
).mapValues(_.toString)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing with greatest impact you can do with that `combineByKey` expression is to size the `StringBuilder` you create so that it does not have to expand its backing character array as you merge string values into it; the resizing amplifies the allocation rate and wastes memory bandwidth by copying from old to new backing array. As a guesstimate, I would say pick the 90th percentile of string length of the resulting data set's records.

A second thing to look at (after collecting some statistics on your intermediate values) would be for your combiner function to pick the `StringBuilder` instance that has room to fit in the other one when you call `sb1.append(sb2)`.

A good thing to take care of would be to use Java 8; it has optimizations that make a significant difference when there's heavy work on strings and string buffers.

Last but not least, profile to see where you are actually spending your cycles. This workload (excluding any additional custom processing you are doing) shouldn't need to promote a lot of objects (if any) to old generation, so you should make sure that young generation has ample size and is collected in parallel.